# How to init array property of annotation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_payment")
data class PaymentEntity(
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
        var user: User? = null) : Serializable {
}
```

as a result of a compilation error: `"Type mismatch"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`cascade`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html#cascade()) annotation attribute accepts an array of [`CascadeType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) thus you need to change your `@ManyToOne` usage to:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = arrayOf(javax.persistence.CascadeType.DETACH))
```